# Decrementing register with 0 in PIC assembly

Tags: assembly, pic, cpu-registers, subtraction, accumulator

If the W register contains 0 and I try to subtract some value from it, what would the value in the register become? Would it set the zero flag inside `STATUS` register and how can I use it to check if we are going to go to negative numbers?

For example, in this code

```
MOVLW b'00000000' ; W has value 0
SUBLW b'00000001' ; trying to decrement
```

I'm trying to decrement W register, what are the consequences of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBLW` will subtract the literal from the value in W regardless of W being zero or not. The result of course will be like

```
W = W - literal;
```

If W = 0 then it's a negation if the type is signed, or a wrap around if it's unsigned.

```
Before: W = 00000000
          -        1
────────────────────
After:  W = 11111111 (-1)
```

But if W is zero, subtract a non-zero number from it will make it non zero, thus the zero flag will not be ON

If you need to check whether the value is negative or not, use both carry flag and zero flag

```
Result    Carry  Zero
Positive  1      0
Zero      1      1
Negative  0      0
```

http://www.pcbheaven.com/picpages/Mathematic_Instructions/

Comment: SUBLW subtracts W from the literal, not the literal from W, more confusing because  the mnemonic order implies W-L. So the original poster's code will always be executed as 0x01 - 0x00, so always giving the answer 0x01. Doing a decrement is easiest by adding the 2s complement using ADDLW 0xFF. That will also set the Carry flag if the result is NOT lower than zero, as per the normal operation of the PIC's C flag for Borrow conditions.